# if then else query in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, case

I have logged in through a session of `User_id`. The `User_id` is in `Profile` table. Now I need to get its class which acts as a column in another table.
Likewise, there are many classes so I would like to use if then else query on my database to get values from another table.
`SELECT class FROM profile`... means class is one of the column of profile where user_id(given)
now using this class that is first (class) it act as a column name in class_table
so if(first)
select first from class_table

```
select class from profile where user_id = session.getattribute("user_id")
if(first)
then
select first from class
else if(second)
then
select second from class...
```

I am using Oracle SQL as the backend and Java and html for front end.
Can someone give the syntax for the above query?

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    class, 
    CASE 
        WHEN xfirst THEN class.first 
        WHEN xsecond THEN class.second 
    END 
from 
    profile 
join 
    class 
on 
    ???? 
where 
    user_id = session.getattribute('user_id')
```

But the logical expressions xfirst and xsecond need revision.  Did not have enough input from you to complete the clause. Same with JOIN.

Comment: sorry but i didnt get on means a query should be there or a table name or what?? can u just give an example

Comment: @user3738332 It's a join condition that goes where the question marks are. You would need to specify which columns in the profile table match with which columns in the class table, since you didn't provide that information in your original post. Presumably you know about joins? If not, I *HIGHLY* recommend you do some research before continuing to work in any database!